# Posting a message to a GUI thread while affecting the result of GetKeyState

Tags: winapi

I know that the `GetKeyState` method, when called from a GUI thread while processing a message retrieved by `GetMessage`, examines the thread's message queue to determine the state of a given key at the time the message was put in the queue.

My question is - is it possible to affect that value in runtime?
I'd want to be able to post a `WM_KEYDOWN` message to a Window, while tweaking the added message such that the receiving thread would think that the CTRL key is pressed. To be clear - I don't want to actually press CTRL - I want only the receiving thread to think that CTRL was pressed.

Is it possible?

Comment: It is technically possible, AttachThreadInput + SetKeyboardState.  You have to be courageous to not use UI Automation to do this.  Especially given that you can't know when the target app processed the message.

Comment: Stop trying, [you can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?